# Append line breaks with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to build a string out of components (a varying number of them)
depending on the type of input. I want to insert line breaks in the resulting `<p>`. But it doesn't work. It simply does nothing.

```
function addToField(input) {
    problemField.append(input).append(" ");
}

function addBreak() {
    console.log('adding break');
    problemField.append("<br/>");
}
```

[`append()` doc](http://api.jquery.com/append/) says you can append HTML strings, so why this does not work?
(it also doesn't work with `<br>` and `\n`)

With:

```
var problemObj = [ { value: 6, operation: '+' }, { value: 2, operation: '-' } ]

addToField(problemObj[0].value);
addBreak();
addToField(problemObj[1].operation);
addToField(problemObj[1].value);
```

The resulting `<p>` is just:

```
<p class="problem">6 - 2 </p>
                     ^---------<br> should be here
```

What can i do?  I want to avoid using `.html()`because it can't be used so easily in a stack-push-manner to generate the string.

Comment: `.append("<br/>")` should work so i'm really not sure how do you test it

Comment: by looking at it :D
that <p class="problem"> is what chrome devtools shows from the actual page

Comment: Ok but i meant your code is missing context and you should provide MCVE, a minimalistic sample replicating your issue because appending `<br/>` element to `p` one would break line

Comment: the problem is, i don't know what else i can show. this is basically everything

Comment: Here it works as expected http://jsfiddle.net/bkpm6nny/  And no, your code isn't everything. We don't know what is `problemObj`

Comment: indeed.... hmm i wonder why it doesn't on my page. could there be another source for errors? like... css?

Comment: It could be many things but CSS could be one: http://jsfiddle.net/bkpm6nny/1/

Comment: i just tried appending a `<br>`from the chrome console, and that WORKS.
so it can't be css...but then i have absolutely no idea what else it could be...

Comment: And what is `problemField`??? Is it a jq object?

Comment: var problemField = $('p.problem');

Comment: Maybe if you provide online link where this issue can be checked, someone could help. For the moment, i don't see any reason it doesn't work regarding your posted code. EDIT: see your code in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3vtymod4/)

Comment: you can check it at http://87.106.160.171:3000/training/1/  (frontend.js lines 55+)
edit:
this is really strange.. i'm sure i will be embarrassed when i find out what's wrong :(

Comment: Ok i think your problem is because you are overriding p content using `text()` method which removes any HTML element from p content. I'm not sure what is the point of it: `var sqrtSolution = $('p.problem').text();
    $('p.problem').html(sqrtSolution.replace(/sqrt\((\d+)\)/gm, "&radic;<span class='root'>$1</span>"));`. Maybe just try: `var sqrtSolution = $('p.problem').html();`

Comment: oh that could actually be it (that is for displaying square roots with the symbol instead of `sqrt`, like it is stored in the db)
thanks! i'll try to find out if this was the problem and if it was, how i can fix it :)

edit: it worked by replacing text() with html(). thank you very much :) i think i wouldn't have found that for a long time :D if you make an answer, i can accept it :)